# Behaviour of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$

Tags: calculus

If $f'(x)$ is decreasing, is it always true that $f''(x)$ is also decreasing?

I want to make sure I understand this concept thoroughly.

Thanks.

Comment: No. Consider $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\log x$.

Answer (score 2):

Forget $f$ for a second and ask a different question: If a function $g$ is decreasing, does that mean that $g'$ is decreasing as well? Now replace $g$ with $f'$, and you have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Arthur, but my question was more so directed towards the second derivative. If the first derivative of a function is decreasing, is the second derivative also decreasing?

Comment: @user292974 Every differentiable function is continuous, so it has an antiderivative. So Arthur's hint is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Plot $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Find $f'(x),f''(x)$.

What can you infer about the question analysing $f''(x),f'(x)$ between $\left[\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$?

[Geogebra](http://web.geogebra.org) easily calculates derivatives (just input $f'(x)$ or $f''(x)$ after defining $f$), pick random functions, experiment for yourself and see.

Comment: Jesse, that definitely helped. Thank you.

Comment: @user292974, as you mentioned in your question, to understand the concept properly, you should try understand Arthur's answer:)

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=$-x^4/12$ is a counter example too .